# AngularJs Kendo Grid Load Sorting on Initialization

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid "GridProjects" (See attachement: Part HTML). At the initialization, the column set (name, field, ...) and the sorted column list are retrieved from my BD on the gridHelperService.

To update the column set, I used the attribute "k-columns" on my HTML. However, I couldn't do the same thing for the sorted columns since the sort proprety is inside datasource.

I Know that I can use k-data-source, but in my case, it doesn't work because my dataSource transport and filter is binded with some variables on the controller.

Every thing is explained at this attachement: [Projects Kendo Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXOHQ.png)

I can't figure out how to fix this, if anyone can give me a hit, I'll appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your setup but based upon the image. Here is what you can try where you want the sort to happen. I don't know the columns your setup has but if you have firstName I would do sort like this.

```
 $scope.GridProjects.dataSource.sort({field: "FirstName", dir: "asc"});
```

Inside the $scope you can get access to the `kendo-grid="GridProjects"` and then its dataSource and then sort it.

Comment: I've already tried this, but it seems like I don't have acces to my GridProjects in the scope. It keeps sayng me that $scope.GridProjects is undefined

Comment: Have you tried getting GridProjects via jQuery and then do sort?

Comment: I tried: var grid = $("#GridProjects").data("kendoGrid"); but it's undefined. When I log the content on the console: console.log($("#GridProjects")), i can see __proto__ which contains the kendo grid data but I have no idea how to access to this

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my settings (columns) are loaded after my grid was created.

I changed my code to created the grid after my settings are loaded. To do, I called my function that creates the grid on my callback function (onSuccess).